# How to remove sharing on onedrive programmatically?

Tags: c#, onedrive, live-sdk

I need to revoke sharing permissions for a file in OneDrive. Is there a way to do this in c#

I have tried so many things to remove sharing like:

shared_edit_link
shared_read_link

I would like to change it to 'Just Me' or remove specific people.